# Функция для нахождения средне арифметического в списке списков

Tags: python, list

Дан cписок списков:

```
complaint_stat = [
              [27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15],
              [12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121],
              [5, 7, 6, 13, 2, 1, 25],
              [15, 6, 14, 19, 25, 7, 3]]
```

1. Нужно найти среднее арифметическое для каждого под_списка:

   ```
   def get_average_number(week_stat):

   #мой код
    return sum(week_stat) // len(week_stat)
   ```
2. Далее посчитать сколько раз средне арифметическое было больше в каждом под_списке соответсветнно:

   ```
   def outlier_days_count(week_stat, week_avg):

   #мой код
    outlier = 0  
    for i in week_stat: 
        if i > week_avg:       
            outlier += 1      
    return outlier
   ```
3. Получение сводной информации:

   ```
   def get_complaint_info(complaint_stat):

   #мой код
        over_avg = outlier_days_count(complaint_stat,get_average_number(complaint_stat))
   for i in complaint_stat: 
    print(i, 'среднее =', get_average_number(i) , ' больше среднего : ', over_avg) 


   # На выходе должны получить
   [27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15]: среднее = 15,  больших среднего: 3
   [12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121]: среднее = 30, больших среднего: 1
   [5, 7, 6, 13, 2, 1, 25]: среднее = 8, больших среднего: 2
   [15, 6, 14, 19, 25, 7, 3]: среднее = 12,  больших среднего: 4
   ```

Это задание из практики, надеюсь передал понятно. Спасибо

Comment: где добавляете результат в массив забыли отступ - в итоге он выполняется вне цикла, т.е. 1 раз

Comment: Код и данные в вопросе должны быть в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

где добавляете результат в массив забыли отступ - в итоге он выполняется вне цикла, т.е. 1 раз

```
def func(data):
    res = []
    for obj in data:
        value = sum(obj) / len(obj)
        res.append(value) # вот тут был забыт отступ
    return res
```

а вообще вы бы могли список и сразу собрать

```
def func(data):
    return [sum(obj) / len(obj) for obj in data]
```

но по хорошему надо бы еще обработать ситуацию, когда список значений пустой

```
def func(data):
    return [(sum(obj) / len(obj)) if len(obj) > 0 else 0 for obj in data]
```

Comment: Среднее арифметическое от пустого списка не думаю, что `0`, скорее такие списки нужно просто пропускать. Ну или `None` выдавать. Почему именно `0`? )

Comment: Вы дали ответ на вопрос, который нарушает правила сайта. Я понимаю ваше желание помочь, но приветствовать неуважение задающего вопрос к сообществу - плохая идея.